# Why does the Mongodb Atlas Search $search operator not return score=1 on exact query match?

Tags: mongodb-atlas-search

My objective is to implement an effect user-name search aggregation with Mongodb Atlas full text search. It's not going super well. Currently I struggle to understand, why the following does not result in a score of 1?

**data**

```
[{name:  "John Doe"}, {"John Eriksen", {"Lara Croft"} ]
```

**Search Index**

```
{ "mappings": { "dynamic": true } }
```

**Pipeline**

```
[
  {
    '$search': {
      'text': {
        'query': 'John Doe', 
        'path': 'name'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$addFields': {
      'score': {
        '$meta': 'searchScore'
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Result**

```
John Doe → 0.66
John Eriksen" → 0.21
```

Why does "John Doe" not return a score of 1, it's an exact score after all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atlas Search is a Lucene-based system, which uses complicated scoring model ([BM25 by default](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25)), taking into account things like term frequency in the document, it's inverse frequency in the whole dataset and documents' length. In this particular example, `text` query also contains 2 terms separated by space, so Lucene will break the overall query down into 2 subqueries and score them independently before sum to a total score. Also note that Lucene scores are relative and valid in the context of a specific query, so their only goal is to order the hits - without any correctness guarantees as an absolute number